# Merging Jar-files?

Tags: java, jar, merge

I already found different description for merging jar-files, like Fat-jar.

However I looked for a simpler solution, like in the below example.

> jar -cmvf ../manifest.m
>   f MyJar.jar lib/*.jar

Maybe someone know the correct syntax to merge two or more jars to one ?

It was merged but the file couldn't be executed.

---

Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath

You may need to reference classes in other JAR files from within a JAR file.

For example, in a typical situation an applet is bundled in a JAR file whose manifest references a different JAR file (or several different JAR files) that serves as utilities for the purposes of that applet.

You specify classes to include in the Class-Path header field in the manifest file of an applet or application. The Class-Path header takes the following form:

```
Class-Path: jar1-name jar2-name directory-name/jar3-name
```

By using the Class-Path header in the manifest, you can avoid having to specify a long -classpath flag when invoking Java to run the your application.
Note: The Class-Path header points to classes or JAR files on the local network, not JAR files within the JAR file or classes accessible over Internet protocols. To load classes in JAR files within a JAR file into the class path, you must write custom code to load those classes. For example, if MyJar.jar contains another JAR file called MyUtils.jar, you cannot use the Class-Path header in MyJar.jar's manifest to load classes in MyUtils.jar into the class path.
An Example

We want to load classes in MyUtils.jar into the class path for use in MyJar.jar. These two JAR files are in the same directory.

We first create a text file named Manifest.txt with the following contents:

```
Class-Path: MyUtils.jar
```

Warning: The text file must end with a new line or carriage return. The last line will not be parsed properly if it does not end with a new line or carriage return.

We then create a JAR file named MyJar.jar by entering the following command:

jar cfm MyJar.jar Manifest.txt MyPackage/*.class

This creates the JAR file with a manifest with the following contents:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: MyUtils.jar
Created-By: 1.7.0_06 (Oracle Corporation)
```

The classes in MyUtils.jar are now loaded into the class path when you run MyJar.jar.

---

Comment: Why even bother to try to combine jars? What will this achieve for you? Why not instead just make sure that both separate jar files can be used?

Comment: I tried to merge it, because I didn't have care about the folder with the libraries,which must be in the same folder as the main jar. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to merge, but supposing that there is some code of yours with a main class and a few simple libraries, you could unzip all other jar files to the same directory, add your classes, add Manifest.mf with [Main-Class:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) header pointing to your main class and then jar (zip) everything back together. This way you overwrite manifests of all the included jar files and possibly other files that have the same name in multiple jars, but you could give it a try.

What you get is a jar file you can run with

```
java -jar myfile.jar
```

and the class defined in Main-Class header will be used as an entry point, it must implement the

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

method.

I do not recommend such solution though, there are other ways that would help you with this task. I know that even this solution can be automatized, but you should probably take a look at maven (eg. [spring-boot:repackage](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html)) or other build tools.

Comment: I didn't know what to write for "classpath" in the Manifest-file and where to place pictures. But somehow I thought someone could know the correct syntax, as described in the Oracle-doc. However I will read about the maven-plugin or other build tools. Thanks